# Slow consumer throuput when using 2 consumer-configuration

Tags: spring, spring-integration, apache-zookeeper, apache-kafka

Using the spring-integration-kafka extention  and the following configuration:

```
<int-kafka:zookeeper-connect id="zookeeperConnect"
    zk-connect="#{kafkaConfig['zooKeeperUrl']}" zk-connection-timeout="10000"
    zk-session-timeout="10000" zk-sync-time="2000" />

<int-kafka:consumer-context id="consumerContext" consumer-timeout="5000" zookeeper-connect="zookeeperConnect">
    <int-kafka:consumer-configurations>
        <int-kafka:consumer-configuration
                group-id="realtime-services-consumer-grp" 
                value-decoder="purchaseDecoder" 
                key-decoder="kafkaReflectionDecoder"
                max-messages="5" >
            <int-kafka:topic id="purchase" streams="1" />
        </int-kafka:consumer-configuration>
        <int-kafka:consumer-configuration 
                group-id="realtime-services-consumer-gw"
                value-decoder="eventDecoder" 
                key-decoder="kafkaReflectionDecoder" 
                max-messages="10" >
            <int-kafka:topic id="event" streams="1" />
        </int-kafka:consumer-configuration>
    </int-kafka:consumer-configurations>
</int-kafka:consumer-context>

<int-kafka:inbound-channel-adapter
    id="kafkaInboundChannelAdapter" kafka-consumer-context-ref="consumerContext"
    auto-startup="true" channel="inputFromKafka">
    <int:poller fixed-delay="20" time-unit="MILLISECONDS" />
</int-kafka:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

When for example I comment the first `consumer-configuration` I can have 300 event per minute with no issue. But when both are activated. I have a very low throughput. Total of throughput coming from both topic is less than a 50 per minutes.

Anyone know why I have such poor performance when reading from 2 topic? What did I do wrong in the configuration?

Comment: What is your `kafkaReflectionDecoder` and others? Can't they be bottlenecks?

Comment: The key is always empty in my message and the  other is the avro decoder. The things is that the bottlenecks happen when I have both consumer, And I have no synchronization in decoder.

Comment: Would you mind taking a look to the `<int-kafka:message-driven-adaptep>`  until we find what's going on? https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/09/spring-integration-kafka-extension-1-0-ga-is-available

Comment: @ArtemBilan it seems to me that this way of consuming message is in a round robin fashion, Since I have a very few message in the topic purchase but a lot of message event it look like it is stuck most of the time polling from purchase. Letting no chance for event to be consume. My CPU is 0% on average. And purchase is not lagging while event have an huge lag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for pointing this out!

After some big fight with my local Kafka claster I have been able to reproduce your issue and I am with some workaround for you :-).

First of all it isn't `round-robin`, but one by one:

```
for (final ConsumerConfiguration<K, V> consumerConfiguration : getConsumerConfigurations().values()) {
    Map<String, Map<Integer, List<Object>>> messages = consumerConfiguration.receive();
```

Where each of those `consumerConfiguration` are blocked on the background during that `consumer-timeout="5000"`, if there is no messages in the `KafkaStream` right now. Hence entire `poll` task from the `<int-kafka:inbound-channel-adapter>` is blocked until that timeout or even worse: if each topic doesn't have message the whole waiting time out is sum of timeouts!

To overcome the issue, you can decrease `consumer-timeout="5000"` or provide several `<int-kafka:consumer-context>` and therefore `<int-kafka:inbound-channel-adapter>` for each topic.

Yes, it looks odd and it is really bad that we haven't found a time to take a look to this before release, but anyway feel free to raise [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INTEXT) issue to fix it.

Thank you!

Comment: Will this issue be fixed in the next upcoming release?

Comment: I have gone with your recommended solution for the time being by creating  multiple consumer context and also reducing consumer-timeout to a much smaller value. It is working fine for my case.