# spring-integration-kafka consumer take a long time to receive message

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, apache-kafka

I using spring-integration-kafka on my project, i can produce and consume messages fine.

I have 1 Producer, 1 High level Consumer, 1 partition for my topic.

When i sent 5msgs/sec, the consumer takes 1 sec to start receiving messages.
But when i tried to use multi threads to send about 300msgs/sec to kafka, i see the consumer takes a long time to start receiving messages, about 5-10 sec. And the larger messages be sent, the slower consumer starts receiving messages. I also tried to add some more configs to decrease the delay time but it seems have no effect.

So any idea or suggestion to help me resolve this issue? I want it always take 0-1sec to start receiving messages. Thanks so much.

This is consumer config:

```
 <int:channel id="inputFromKafka">
            <int:dispatcher task-executor="kafkaMessageExecutor" />
        </int:channel>

        <int-kafka:zookeeper-connect id="zookeeperConnect"
            zk-connect="127.0.0.1:2181" zk-connection-timeout="6000"
            zk-session-timeout="6000" zk-sync-time="2000" />

        <int-kafka:inbound-channel-adapter
            id="kafkaInboundChannelAdapter" kafka-consumer-context-ref="consumerContext"
            auto-startup="true" channel="inputFromKafka">
            <int:poller fixed-delay="10" time-unit="MILLISECONDS"
                max-messages-per-poll="5" />
        </int-kafka:inbound-channel-adapter>


        <bean id="consumerProperties"
            class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
            <property name="properties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="auto.offset.reset">smallest</prop>
                    <prop key="socket.receive.buffer.bytes">1048576</prop>
                    <prop key="fetch.message.max.bytes">5242880</prop>
                    <prop key="auto.commit.interval.ms">10</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>

        <int-kafka:consumer-context id="consumerContext"
            consumer-timeout="1000" zookeeper-connect="zookeeperConnect"
            consumer-properties="consumerProperties">
            <int-kafka:consumer-configurations>
                <int-kafka:consumer-configuration
                    group-id="defaultGp" max-messages="10000">
                    <int-kafka:topic id="testTopic" streams="4" />
                </int-kafka:consumer-configuration>
            </int-kafka:consumer-configurations>
        </int-kafka:consumer-context>

        <task:executor id="kafkaMessageExecutor" pool-size="0-10"
            keep-alive="120" queue-capacity="500" />

        <int:outbound-channel-adapter channel="inputFromKafka"
            ref="kafkaConsumer" method="processMessage" />
```

And the producer:

```
<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="inputToKafka" />

<int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter
    id="kafkaOutboundChannelAdapter" kafka-producer-context-ref="kafkaProducerContext"
    auto-startup="true" order="1" channel="inputToKafka" />
<int-kafka:producer-context id="kafkaProducerContext"
    producer-properties="producerProps">
    <int-kafka:producer-configurations>
        <int-kafka:producer-configuration 
            broker-list="127.0.0.1:9092"
            async="true" topic="testTopic"
            key-class-type="java.lang.String" 
            key-encoder="encoder"
            value-class-type="java.lang.String" 
            value-encoder="encoder"
            compression-codec="default" />
    </int-kafka:producer-configurations>
</int-kafka:producer-context>

<util:properties id="producerProps">
    <prop key="queue.buffering.max.ms">500</prop>
    <prop key="topic.metadata.refresh.interval.ms">360000</prop>
    <prop key="queue.buffering.max.messages">10000</prop>
    <prop key="retry.backoff.ms">100</prop>
    <prop key="message.send.max.retries">5</prop>
    <prop key="send.buffer.bytes">5242880</prop>
    <prop key="socket.request.max.bytes">104857600</prop>
    <prop key="socket.receive.buffer.bytes">1048576</prop>
    <prop key="socket.send.buffer.bytes">1048576</prop>
    <prop key="request.required.acks">1</prop>
</util:properties>

<bean id="encoder"
    class="org.springframework.integration.kafka.serializer.common.StringEncoder" />


<task:executor id="taskExecutor" pool-size="5"
    keep-alive="120" queue-capacity="500" />
```

Comment: Try to make `max-messages="10000"` equal to the `max-messages-per-poll="5"`. From other side it would be better to make it based on the `<int-kafka:message-driven-channel-adapter>`

Comment: Thanks Artem, i tried but it still got delay.

Comment: Looks like you are facing the same issue like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28412482/slow-consumer-throuput-when-using-2-consumer-configuration. So, try to decrease that `consumer-timeout="1000"`

Comment: Did you fixed this issue? facing something similar