# Why is Kafka Consumer blocked until timeout, even if there are messages?

Tags: spring-integration, apache-kafka

I am using high level client (legacy code) with kafka.

However, I have observed that even if there are MANY message available on the topic, the consumer is still blocked until the zk-connection-timeout time passes by.

Why is this and how can I workaround this? I am interested in - is there a message found? move further.

```
<int-kafka:zookeeper-connect id="zookeeperConnect"
    zk-connect="#{kafkaConfig['zooKeeperUrl']}" zk-connection-timeout="5000"
    zk-session-timeout="5000" zk-sync-time="2000" />

<int-kafka:consumer-context id="consumerContext" consumer-timeout="5000" zookeeper-connect="zookeeperConnect">
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's a know issue with the High Level Consumer implementation, when you use several topics, configurations, when each `KafkaStream` is blocked and involved in the same sequential iteration process.

See [Slow consumer throuput when using 2 consumer-configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28412482/slow-consumer-throuput-when-using-2-consumer-configuration) for more information.

**UPDATE**

The `consumer-timeout` means exactly this in the `ConsumerIterator` from the `KafkaStream`:

```
currentDataChunk = (FetchedDataChunk)this.channel().poll((long)this.consumerTimeoutMs, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

where that `channel` is just `BlockingQueue`. I think no surprise here why we are blocked during the message retrieval for that `consumer-timeout`.

From other, please, find `max-messages` option on the `<int-kafka:consumer-configuration>`. It is `1` by default.

Comment: thank you very much for the answer. I am very new to this topic. Let's say that I have a message that would normally be read in 5 seconds. If I set the connection timeout on 2 seconds, so less than a message would actually get read, what will happen? is the connect timeout just "the time to check if there is a message or not" or "the time to check if there is a message and also read that message in the same time range"? Thank you very much

Comment: I tried on a single topic and it does the following: process the message and wait until the consumer timeout is finished and only afther that reads a new message. e.g. consumer-timeout=5 seconds; processing time=1 second - it will wait 4 seconds until fetching a new message

Comment: could you please tell me if is there a way to say that if the max-number of messages is gathered, then do not wait any longer?

Comment: it seems that the timout comes from waiting on all streams (partitions) to be a message.

Comment: Not sure why you need such a functionality, but you can simply minimize the `timeout` and wait there just for a short period. Anyway the `<int-kafka:inbound-channel-adapter>` is `pollable`, so there is some time in between different polls and that won't be surprise that we may wait there for nothing.